# Eliminar impresoras .bat

Tags: vb.net, batch, vbscript

Buen dia

Lo que pasa es que tengo una app en vb que crea impresoras invocando por medio de un cmd las ordenes ,pide puerto y nombre ,el problema es que si el puerto ya esta creado lo que hace es crear una cola de impresion,hay alguna manera de borrar esa impresora pasando como parametro la ip ,por ejemplo la siguiente linea borra todas las impresoras locales

```
cscript %windir%\SysWOW64\Printing_Admin_Scripts\es-ES\prnmngr.vbs -xo
```

Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 1):

> ...hay alguna manera de borrar esa impresora pasando como parametro la
>   ip ,por ejemplo la siguiente linea borra todas las impresoras locales

Podrías intentar borrar la impresora pasando su nombre:

```
@echo off
RUNDLL32.EXE PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /dn /n "ImpresoraABorrar"
EXIT
```

Guardas el archivo con extensión *.bat y lo ejecutas como administrador.

Comment: Buen día gracias, si ya lo había hecho pasando el nombre, pero quería saber si pasando la ip podría borrar, pero leí documentación y creo que no es posible, mucha gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: De nada, estamos para ayudarnos  :D